# C++ String.Format implementation error

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement the same function as `C#`'s `String.Format` in `C++`. However, I have a problem with the output in some cases:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class format_base
{
public:
    format_base(const char *base) : argp_(0)
    {
        base_ = (char*)calloc(4097, sizeof(char));
        sz_ = 4097;
        memcpy(base_, base, strlen(base));
    };
    ~format_base()
    {
        free(base_);
    }
    format_base &arg(const char *argument)
    {
        if ((strlen(base_) - 3) + strlen(argument) > sz_)
        {
            base_ = (char*)realloc(base_, (sz_ *= 2));
        }
        std::string elim = "{";
        elim.append(std::to_string(argp_++));
        elim.append("}");
        std::string tbase = base_;
        size_t f = tbase.find(elim.c_str());
        if (f != std::string::npos)
        {
            tbase.replace(f, elim.size(), argument);
        }
        memcpy(base_, tbase.c_str(), tbase.length());
        return *this;
    }
    char *value()
    {
        return base_;
    }
    char *operator()()
    {
        return base_;
    }
private:
    char *base_;
    size_t argp_, sz_;
};

format_base &format(const char *base)
{
    return *new format_base(base);
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << format("Hello {0}").arg("a")(); // Prints "Hello a0} "
    std::cout << format(" Hello {0}").arg("ab")(); // Prints " Hello ab} "
    std::cout << format(" Hello {0}\n").arg("abc")(); // Prints " Hello abc\n"
    std::cout << format("Hello {0}\n").arg("a")(); // Prints "Hello a\n}"
    std::cout << format("Hello {0}\n").arg("ab")(); // Prints "Hello ab\n"
    std::cout << format("Hello {0}\n").arg("abc")(); // Prints "Hello abc\n"
    getchar();
}
```

Total output:

> Hello a0} Hello ab} Hello abc
>
> Hello a
>
> }
>
> Hello ab
>
> _
>
> Hello abc
>
> _

I am very confused and I would be very grateful if you could help

Comment: There's already a `std::to_string` function that returns a proper `std::string`. No need to make another that returns a C string.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use std::string everywhere instead of manually managing memory?

Comment: @SebastianRedl - I prefer it this way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you forgot to set the string length properly. The "bad" output is just the result string and the last characters of the old string. You need to cut off the string if it is shortened by the replacement.

```
memcpy(base_, tbase.c_str(), tbase.length());
```

`length()` doesn't count the terminating `\0`, so you probably want

```
strcpy(base_, tbase.c_str());
```

or

```
memcpy(base_, tbase.c_str(), tbase.length()+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should replace:

```
    memcpy(base_, tbase.c_str(), tbase.length());
```

with:

```
    strcpy(base_, tbase.c_str());
```

where have you planned to free memory from this allocations? :

```
return *new format_base(base);
char *s = (char*)calloc(2, sizeof(char));
```